# Using a variable for the key value when using head_object - Amazon S3 Boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm attempting to get the file size of all files in a given S3 bucket. The S3 bucket is passed in via a command line argument. Aftwerwards, the python script loops over each object found in the bucket and gets the file size to print to the screen. There is more that will be added later. But at the moment, I'm stuck on assigning a variable to the Key value.

So far I've tried a few things with a few errors. Prior to getting in to that, if I use the same code, but assign the Key value to something hard coded, it works like a charm. I've attempted to convert the variable to a string value, via str(thing) and repr(thing), this was due to receiving an error that the "thing" variable was not read as a string.

I then attempted to use curly braces with the variable as evident in the commented out line Key="{thing}". I did this with and without quotes. Without quotes, gave an error that key was not a valid type 'str'.

```
import boto3
import sys

# Connect S3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3Client = boto3.client("s3")

# List S3 buckets
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)

bucket1 = s3.Bucket(sys.argv[1])

sourceBucket = sys.argv[1]

for thing in bucket1.objects.all():
    print(thing.key)
#    thing = str(thing)
#    newThing = str(thing)
    fileSize = s3Client.head_object(
      Bucket=sourceBucket,
#      Key="{thing}"
#      Key=newThing
      Key="Monkey_puppet.jpg"
    )
    print(fileSize['ContentLength'])
```

Nearly every error has a variation of this. Lines 357 and 661 in client.py are consistently referenced.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./testScript.py", line 25, in <module>
        Key=newThing,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
        return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
        raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found
```

When using Key={thing}

```
    Invalid type for parameter Key, value: {s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='my-python-testbucket-1', key='Monkey_puppet.jpg')}, type: <class 'set'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
```

When using Key='{thing}'

```
    botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found
```

When using Key=thing

```
    Invalid type for parameter Key, value: s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='my-python-testbucket-1', key='Monkey_puppet.jpg'), type: <class 'boto3.resources.factory.s3.ObjectSummary'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
```

And then when converting thing to a string via thing=str(thing)

```
    botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found
```

At this point, I'm just shooting in the dark on how Key= will use a variable instead of a hardcoded value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in the "key" to the S3 Client object:

```py
for thing in bucket1.objects.all():
    print(thing.key)
    fileSize = s3Client.head_object(
      Bucket=sourceBucket,
      Key=thing.key
    )
    print(fileSize['ContentLength'])
```

Though, really, you don't need to head the object to get its size.  The various S3 APIs that enumerate files all return the size in some form:

```py
for thing in bucket1.objects.all():
    print(thing.key)
    print(thing.size)
```

Not only is it faster, it also means far fewer API calls.

Comment: You have saved my sanity. I must have missed something of this in the documentation I was looking at here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html

Any chance there is another place for documentation that I can look at or use later?